# How can I copy text from a website, using my Adobe Flex application?

Tags: flash, web-scraping

How can I copy text from a website, using my Adobe Flex application? I can't select text, and OCR software doesn't copy exactly the same text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always right click and show view page source.
If that doesn't work, click F12 in Chrome. 
If the text is image based, then there's no way except OCR.

Could you give me the website so I can mess around a bit?

Hope you'll find your answer.

Cheers